# Applying yaw_offset and mag_declination in IMU driver

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am writing an IMU driver (for an IMU that will be fused with GPS using robot_localization) and want to make sure I am applying yaw_offset and mag_declination the same way robot_localization does it so there is no need to set those parameters in robot_localization. The data from the IMU (called `raw_imu`) has been set to the right ROS convention but forward is North (therefore the need for yaw offset).
Is the right way to create a yaw rotation quaternion with the two parameters and then apply that to the raw IMU data as follows?

```
YAW_OFFSET = 1.570796327
MAG_DECL = -0.1455605   #  at my location declination is 8° 17' E
yaw_transform = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, YAW_OFFSET+MAG_DECL)
imu_transformed = tf.transformations.quaternion_multiply(yaw_transform, raw_imu)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282452/applying-yaw_offset-and-mag_declination-in-imu-driver/) by [boost](https://answers.ros.org/users/24400/boost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should be pretty easy to test using `bpython`:

```
>>> from tf import transformations
>>> raw = transformations.quaternion_from_euler(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
>>> offset = transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0.0, 0.0, 0.3)
>>> print(transformations.euler_from_quaternion(transformations.quaternion_multiply(raw, offset
)))
(1.1668867925697146, 0.7335759265998189, 1.2166525164145243)
>>> print(transformations.euler_from_quaternion(transformations.quaternion_multiply(offset, raw
)))
(1.0000000000000002, 0.9999999999999999, 1.3000000000000003)
```

So the rotation you want is indeed `yaw_transform * raw_imu`. This is verified via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation):

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1